# How to px-sized content in %-sized div using html

Tags: html, overflow

I'm trying to fit in a google plus widget inside a div that has dimensions in %... but the widget has dimensions in px... so when i place the widget inside the div it flows out of the div on changing screen resolutions...
markup is like this:

```
<div style="width:100%">
  <script src="http://..." width="360px" .... ></script>
</div>
```

any help would be great...

Comment: what is the desired effect? Do you want scroll bars to appear? do you want content to be hidden?

Comment: actually...i dont want scrollbars...or i would have set the overflow to scroll...setting the min-height(i feel like a complete noob...no thinking of that earlier :)) fixes the issues...as said by Kirk...

Comment: glad to hear you got it resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the min-width property so that way the div never goes below 360px. A `div` will by deffault take 100% of the width space given unless you specify a smaller width or set other properties that change it's size.

```
<div style="min-width:360px;">
  <script src="http://..." width="360px" .... ></script>
</div>
```